# Different behavior in different browsers with neither yielding the desired result

Tags: css, html

I'm wanting the text in the navigation bar to display a different color when the user is on that page so the user knows where they are. I can get this to work in all the browsers with just a single page, but things get funny when I start working with the children pages. In Chrome the parent page, a placeholder link (active4) responds but so do all the children pages (active4a-c), in both IE and Mozilla the individual child page (active4a) responds but the parent page (active4) doesn't. The CSS  for these classes are in an internal style sheet so once you leave the page the links revert to the style in the external style sheet.

```
  <li class="active4" ><a href="#" >Reviewers</a>
        <ul>
        <li class="active4a"><a href="reviewers.html">Reviewer Information</a></li>
        <li class="active4b" ><a href="#" >How</a></li>
        <li class="active4c"><a href="#" >Future</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

.active4 a:visited {
    color:#6206F7;
}
.active4a a:visited {
    color:#6206F7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the :visited pseudo-selector is what you want.  This selects the `<a>` tag after it has been visited even once.  So, once a visitor clicks on the link, it will always be the new color.  Instead, try creating an `active` class that only selects `<a>` elements that are children.  Here is some working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            a:link {
                color:blue;
            }
            a:visited {
                color:blue;
            }
            .active > a:link {
                color:red;
            }
            .active > a:visited {
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="active" ><a href="#" >Reviewers</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="reviewers.html">Reviewer Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >How</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Future</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The one thing I want to point out is the `>` between the `.active` and the `a:link`.  This selects only `<a>` tags that are children of the `.active`.  If you omit this, it will select all descendents which will lead to the problem you were having earlier.

Comment: Thanks zsat,I will try the > and see what happens. I'm using the :visited pseudo-selector based on another comment feed I found here. By not putting it in the external style sheet the links don't retain the color. When in a child page the parent link in the nav bar displays the visited color (correct), but when the user goes into the sub-menu under that parent all the children links display the same color when only the child page the user is on should display that color. Hence the reason for giving each child their own class name.

Comment: .active4b  a:visited {
 color:#E711F4;
}
.active4c  a:visited {
 color:#E711F4;
}

Comment: While the :visited pseudo-selector may work in an internal stylesheet, I would encourage you to change your code and put it in an external stylesheet.  If you use the internal stylesheet, you will have a copy of it on every page.  Imagine how much of a pain it will be to change that color later, especially when you have 100's of pages.  That is why external stylesheets are the preferred method.  They allow you to make changes to a single stylesheet and have it applied across the site.

Comment: I agree it would be preferable to put it into an external style sheet, but wouldn't that then leave all the links that are visited in the visited color? I ended up having to modify my approach, only the page being displayed gets the :visited pseudo-selector, all the others get :link. I tried :focus with no success, I tried adding span tags to the text element of the link and styling a class in the <li> but nothing has worked. It would seem the ideal place for some kind of equation IF x = y THEN A  [link] (http://students.csitech.net/MBrackett/cisw113/bookvetter/index.html)

Comment: You can set :visited to the :link color for all links.  This is probably normal for navigation.  Then the current page is highlighted with the `.active` class.  That way any link that is not of the `.active` class will look the same whether or not they have been visited.

Comment: I may have come across another possibility, at least I've got some options to consider now. Thanks [link](http://www.mstudiostalk.com/2008/03/11/pure-css-to-display-the-active-page-in-the-navigation/)